# How to vectorize sub2ind?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a 2 dimensional array `L`, and I am trying to create a vector of linear indices `ind` for each row of this array.

```
L=
1 5 25 4 0 0 
2 3 3 45 5 6
45 5 6 0 0 0
```

I am using `lenr` to store the number of non zero elements in each row (starting from column 1).

```
lenr=
4
6
3
```

Then I have 1x45 array `RULES`. Indices stored in `L` refer to elements in `RULES`. Since I want to vectorize the code, I decided to create linear indices and then run `RULES(ind)`.

This works perfectly:

```
ind=sub2ind(size(L),1,lenr(1));
```

while this doesn't work:

```
ind=sub2ind(size(L),1:3,1:lenr(1:3));
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I initially tried to vectorize the code, but it did not works and that's why I checked linear indices:

```
rul=repmat(RULES,3);
result = rul((L(1:J,1:lenr(1:J))));
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @excaze: Look my updates.

Comment: Why are you using `1:lenr(1:3)` instead of `lenr(1:3)`?

Comment: @excaza: I use 1:lenr(1:3) in order to get L elements FROM 1 TO the corresponding length for each row (lenr contains lengths excluding 0s).

Comment: Create a mask with `L~=0` and use it on a list of all linear indices `1:numel(L)`'s 2D reshaped version (to match L's size) to get such selective linear indices?

Comment: @Divakar: I appreciate if you could give some example.

Comment: Here let me *feed* you - `allind = reshape(1:numel(L),size(L,1),[])` and then `ind = allind(L~=0)`. Not tested though.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos If you tested what you're trying to do you'd see `1:lend(1:3)` returns `[1 2 3 4]`. I would suggest learning how to [debug your code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html).

Comment: @excaza: Why do you think I yell at you??! I just marked key words with capslock...

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpret your edit, you want to create a variable `result` that contains the elements of `RULES` indicated by the non-zero elements of `L`. Note that in general, the best way to vectorize `sub2ind` is to not use `sub2ind`.

If you want `result` to be a linear array, you can simply write

```
%// transpose so that result is ordered by row
L_transposed = L.'; 
result = RULES(L_transposed(L_transposed>0));
```

If, instead, you want `result` to be an array of the same size as `L`, with all numbers in `L` replaced by the corresponding element in `RULES`, it's even simpler:

```
result = L;
result(result>0) = RULES(result>0);
```